# Copy folders recursively with cmd with a string

Tags: string, list, batch-file, for-loop, copy

I have to copy files that are in folder. I did the copy based on a .txt file. The problem is that now I have around 1500 folders that are created by users, who rename them as they want. The only thing that all the folders have in common is an **id number** that is unique followed by random text. For example:

1111 folder1
2222-folder-important 1
3333 important-folder

I have a list with the id but when I run the .bat it copies all the folders and subfolders that **are** and **aren’t** on the list and doesn’t copy the files.
This is the script:

```
Rem This is a simple log
    date /t >> Z:\DES\destination\log.txt

Rem List the current folder were the subfolders are
    dir /b "Z:\DES\test\" > dir.txt

Rem Navigate and compare the folders
    FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN (lista.txt) DO (
        FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (dir.txt) DO (
            IF %%F == %%G  (xcopy /I /E "Z:\DES\test\%%G" "Z:\DES\destination\%%G" >> Z:\DES\destination\log.txt)
    )
)

Rem comparing the variables
    REM If %%F == %%G
```

Tried with a wildcard without success.

The file list contains the id:

1111
2222
3333
**. . .**

I have tried the following in the list without success:

1111*
“1111”
1111%

Please help. And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Your nested For loops aren't working because (as @MCND told me) "for each iteration of the outer For _all_ iterations of the inner loop are executed." Try searching here for "nested for loops." There are many examples and solutions. NOTE: Look at the list of Related questions on this page.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `if` with wildcards. A better way:

```
echo %%G |findstr "^%%F" >nul && copy...
```

echo the filename (`%%G`), check if it starts (`^`) with your IDnumber (`%%F`) (redirecting output to `nul` to keep the screen clear) and if it does (`&&`), copy it.

Comment: FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN (lista.txt) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (dir.txt) DO echo %%G |findstr "^%%F" >nul &&  xcopy /I /E "Z:\DES\test\%%G" "Z:\DES\destination\%%G" >> Z:\DES\destination\log.txt

Comment: i double checked and i had an space, looks like is working now. did the test with some test folders and looks good. now i am doing the test on the server with 1300 folders will take some time. THANK YOU a lot for your help

Comment: well, I assume, you wouldn't have been much quicker doing it by hand :D Consider to accept the answer so your quesition is marked as solved.